# Drupal 7 - Cannot delete content

Tags: drupal-7, nodes, content-type

This is rather odd: I am suddenly unable to delete content from my Drupal 7 website.

I can no longer delete any content, regardless of the content type. When I click delete and confirm, I return to the content overview, but the items are still there (and accessible). No errors, no warnings, no error logs. Flushing the cache does not help. I'm logged in as admin, so I cannot be a permission-issue. The url aliases however *are* deleted, the nodes themselves not.

I haven't done any core hacking, or installed weird modules, it's a rather basic Drupal installation. Any thoughts on how to delete content again, or how I can try to figure out what's happening here? Much appreciated!

Comment: Closed, thanks. Turned out a module somehow created a Trigger, that referred to the content-overview page when the delete-button was hit. This took place before the content actually got deleted. Deleting the Trigger did the trick.

Comment: If it was a contributed module, can you name it? It might help others while debugging problems like specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  I checked the 'error log' and saw a possible conflict with the "Heartbeat Plugin" part of the "Heartbeat" module.  As soon as I turned that plugin off (via the "modules" section), the issue was resolved.